# How can I decline an INSERT when column is set to NOT NULL

Tags: clickhouse

From the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#null-modifiers), you have to put a NOT NULL modifier in the column definition to mark it as such, just like for other SQL databases.

Consider this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    name String NOT NULL,
    isodate DateTime('Europe/Berlin') NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (isodate)
```

If I would try to insert NULL for both columns (or at least one), the expected behaviour is that Clickhouse declines insertion since the columns are marked as NOT NULL. Instead, Clickhouse creates a new row, where `isodate` is 1970-01-01 01:00:00 and `name` is an empty string, which are the default values for those data types apparently.

What do I have to do so that Clickhouse declines such inserts?

My Clickhouse server version is 21.12.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ClickHouse, `NULL` and `NOT NULL` do change the behavior of the data type, but not in the way other relational databases - it is syntactically compatible with other relational database but not semantically (`a Int32 NULL` is the same as `a Nullable(Int32)`, as `a Int32 NOT NULL` is the same as `a Int32`). A column defined as `NOT NULL` does not mean it will refuse to insert fields whose values are `NULL` in the insert statement - it means ClickHouse will use the default expression for the column type (or if it is not specified in the column definition, the default value for the data type). This behavior is expected in ClickHouse when `input_format_null_as_default` is enabled (the default for Clickhouse 21.12.3).

To throw exceptions for such invalid values you need to change the system setting `input_format_null_as_default` to 0. If you use `clickhouse-client`, you can disable it while connecting to clickhouse:

```
clickhouse-client -h ... --input_format_null_as_default 0
```

or after:

```
clickhouse> SET input_format_null_as_default=0
```

This way, a statement like `insert into test (name, isodate) values (NULL, NULL);` will behave more likely most relational databases.

Comment: Thanks! This works if you issue "SET input_format_null_as_default=0" inside the terminal, but only as long as you are inside the terminal session. For our application we would like to insert data with the HTTP interface, or reuse the setting in a new terminal session; in other words make the setting persistent. I set the setting in users.xml, and "select * from system.settings" tells me that Clickhouse has indeed parsed the correct value from users.xml. Nevertheless, once I try to insert NULL values over the HTTP interface or through the terminal, it goes through. Any idea on that?

Comment: I could make it work setting the option in the server url, like: `http://localhost:8123/?input_format_null_as_default=0&query=....` (returns exception `Code: 53. DB::Exception: Cannot insert NULL value into a column of type 'String' at: NULL,NULL`). Which language/driver are you using?

Comment: I use Javascript without any wrapper around the HTTP interface of Clickhouse. Passing the argument in the URL is actually sufficient for my use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Clickhouse behaviour with `Not Null` constraints is not compatible with other databases.

You can overcome it using check constraints https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#constraints

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    name String NOT NULL,
    isodate DateTime('Europe/Berlin') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT isodate_not_null CHECK isodate <> toDateTime(0, 'Europe/Berlin')
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY (isodate)


insert into test(name) values ('x');
DB::Exception: Constraint `isodate_not_null` for table default.test (f589312a-1592-426a-b589-312a1592b26a) is violated at row 1. Expression: (isodate != toDateTime(0)). Column values: isodate = 0. (VIOLATED_CONSTRAINT)


insert into test values ('x', now());
OK.
```

The reason is performance, in OLAP databases need to ingest data as fast as possible.

Comment: I have not tried this approach since I went with Anselmo's solution, but I'd still like to thank you for your suggestion, which may help others.